# class gets parsed in eclipse, but fails in netbeans - generics

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, hbase

I have a strange behaviour when having a class in netbeans and eclipse.

the following class compiles OK in eclipse (juno), but netbeans (7.3) tells me that "MyComparator is not abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo(Object) from Comparable". the source is set to use version 1.7.

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.WritableByteArrayComparable;

public class MyComparator extends WritableByteArrayComparable {
protected int offset;

public MyComparator () {
}

public MyComparator (byte[] mask, int offset) {
       //...
}

@Override
public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
      // do something
}

@Override
public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
      // do something
}

public int compareTo(byte[] value) {
    //do something here
}
}
```

What can I do to make it work in netbeans as well?

EDIT: the version of hbase is 0.92.1 - the abstract class can be found eg. here: http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/hbase-0.92.1-cdh4.0.0/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/WritableByteArrayComparable.html

Comment: What version of the library that has the class `WritableByteArrayComparable` are you using in each one? Probably, you are using different version and one forces you to override an abstract method.

Comment: its both the same version of hbase, 0.92.1

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it compiled in eclipse. May be different versions of WritableByteArrayComparable are present in your eclipse and net beans class path.

But WritableByteArrayComparable is an abstract class and you have not implemented all its abstract methods. Check the [link](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/hbase/hbase-0.94.1/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/WritableByteArrayComparable.java.html).

Atleast this one is not implemented

```
public abstract int compareTo(byte [] value, int offset, int length);
```

Comment: i'm using version 0.92.1, this method is not included there yet. I updated the question to include the version number

Comment: Can you check the source of `WritableByteArrayComparable` which is being used in both cases. You might find a difference. If you don't have source just use decompiler. Meanwhile you can override the method I mentioned and check if it works.

Comment: there is one difference with the projects though. the one in netbeans uses maven, the one in eclipse doesn't. but the versions of the libraries are the same, so this shouldn't be an issue (as I just checked that the class contains the same.

Comment: What we are up to here now is that there should be a compilation error but it doesn't show in eclipse. I don't want to sound non-technical, but may be you can clean your project in eclipse and restart it. You might notice the compilation error. Sometimes eclipse fools us. :-)

Comment: yep, that I know of eclipse ;) but this works for a few month now, so it can't be an issue with eclipse, as it was built and rebuilt several times. it must be some problem with netbeans, but I can't figure out which...maybe I ask netbeans directly. thanks though